# I can't access Twilio Studio Execution Contexts via PHP library?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-studio

I have a simple flow where callers record a message using the "Record Voicemail" widget, then I post the execution's Flow SID, the Execution SID, and the Call SID to my PHP app so I can download the recorded MP3.

The PHP app successfully gets the POSTed data, but when I try to use:

```
$execution_context = $client->studio->v2->flows("$flowSid")
                                    ->executions("$executionSid")
                                    ->executionContext()
                                    ->fetch();
```

I'm getting this error in the logs, isn't super clear (to me, anyway :-) :

*mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 404] Unable to fetch record: The requested resource /Flows//Executions//Context was not found in /home/me/public_html/vendor/twilio/src/Twilio/Version.php:88*

The context **is** available if I enter that same FlowSid and ExecutionSid into the Console API Explorer, I just don't seem to be able to get it in my app using the PHP library.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!